# Delete hdfs path after executing the action in oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

How do I delete a hdfs path after executing an action similar to the prepare tag which deletes before the action.

```
<workflow-app name="[WF-DEF-NAME]" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
    ...
    <action name="[NODE-NAME]">
        <pig>
            <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
            <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
            <prepare>
               <delete path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
               <mkdir path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
            </prepare>
            <job-xml>[JOB-XML-FILE]</job-xml>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>[PROPERTY-NAME]</name>
                    <value>[PROPERTY-VALUE]</value>
                </property>
                ...
            </configuration>
            <script>[PIG-SCRIPT]</script>
            <param>[PARAM-VALUE]</param>
                ...
            <param>[PARAM-VALUE]</param>
            <argument>[ARGUMENT-VALUE]</argument>
                ...
            <argument>[ARGUMENT-VALUE]</argument>
            <file>[FILE-PATH]</file>
            ...
            <archive>[FILE-PATH]</archive>
            ...
        </pig>
        <ok to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
        <error to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: I dont think there are any such option to delete directory post action, I would add command to delete desired directory at the end of pig script.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent in the pig action.

You basically have two options:

- Add delete commands inside your pig script
- Add a [fs action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action) either in the `ok` element or in both `ok` and `error` elements. Note that you need two different actions if you want the flows for success or failure to differ after the deletion.

Comment: I was also thinking of adding a FS action to do so, It would be good if such a feature is available.